Каким образом можно бесплатно и без заморочек отправлять запросы и принимать их на с++
Пишу одну программу(не суть какую) которая должна отправлять запросы и принимать их. Одна проблема: я не хочу использовать локальные сервера. А глобальные сервера не любят черных, а любят белых(а если что про айпи адреса. Наверное). Хорошим вариантом было использовать бота в телеграм, но я хочу всю программу написать на с++, а не частями на python. Есть ли ещё варианты бесплатно, и без трехэтажного мата на провайдера с просьбой открыть порты, отправлять и принимать запросы?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Что бы работать с ботами тебе не обязательно использовать Phyton (можно работать с ними и на плюсах простой пример), Telegram Api работает поверх https протокола, зачем тебе открытые порты?
Библиотека для работы с телеграмм ботами на с++ - tgbot
